# Master curve of the 3D Ising model

Tags: computational-physics, phase-transition, ising-model

I am currently doing some grand canonical Monte Carlo simulations for LJ particles and my professor has asked me to map the normalized probability distribution of density on to a master curve of the 3D Ising model.

I understand that since the 3D Ising model's phase transition and liquid-gas transition fall under same universality class, they should have some relation. However, on searching the internet for the master curve of the Ising model I come up with rather different looking curves.

My $P(N)$ vs $N$ graph for LJ particles looks like a two peaked function. So can anybody please provide some information and details about this 3D master curve and its relation with the liquid-gas phase transition?

Can you also correct me if I am thinking incorrectly in fitting the $P(N)$ vs $N$ curve to it?